# Parsing multiple lines from a txt output

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I need to parse a part of my output file that looks like this (Image is also attached for clarity)

y,mz) = (-.504D-04,-.543D-04,-.538D-03)

```
The expected output is :
```

```
the code I have so far looks like below:
```

class NACParser(ParseSection):
name = "coupling"

which is good but there are some issues:

1. It only prints from the very last line and this, I think, is because it overwrites due to similar other lines.
2. This code will only work for this specific molecule and I want something that can work for any molecule. What I mean is : in this example - I have a molecule with 15 atoms and the first atom is c (carbon) , 5th atom is h (hydrogen) and 11th atom is s (sulfur) but the total number of atoms (which is currently 15 ) and the name of atoms can be different when I have different molecule.

So I am wondering how can I write a general code that can work for a general molecule . Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will to literally what you asked.  Maybe you can use this as a basis.  I just gather all the atom IDs when I find a line with "ATOM", and create the dict entries when I find a line with "d/d".  I would show the output, but I just typed in faked data because I didn't want to retype all of that.

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

header = r"(\d+ [a-z]{1,2})"

atoms = []
gather = {}
for line in open('x.txt'):
    if len(line) < 5:
        continue
    if 'ATOM' in line:
        atoms = re.findall( header, line )
        atoms = [s.replace(' ','') for s in atoms]
        continue
    if '/d' in line:
        parts = line.split()
        row = parts[0].replace('/','')
        for at,val in zip(atoms,parts[1:]):
            gather[at+'_'+row] = val
pprint(gather)
```

Here's the output from your test data.  I hope you realize that the cut-and-paste data doesn't match the image.  The image uses `d/dx`, but the cut and paste uses `dE/dx`.  I have assumed you want the "E" in the dict tag too, but that's easy to fix if you don't.

```
{'10c_dEdx': '0.8337613D-02',
 '10c_dEdy': '-0.8171767D-01',
 '10c_dEdz': '-0.4316928D-02',
 '11s_dEdx': '0.3138990D-01',
 '11s_dEdy': '0.3893252D-01',
 '11s_dEdz': '0.2767787D-02',
 '12h_dEdx': '0.8416159D-02',
 '12h_dEdy': '0.3335059D-02',
 '12h_dEdz': '0.1357569D-01',
 '13h_dEdx': '0.1128067D-02',
 '13h_dEdy': '-0.1457401D-01',
 '13h_dEdz': '-0.7834375D-03',
 '14h_dEdx': '0.8941240D-02',
 '14h_dEdy': '0.4869915D-02',
 '14h_dEdz': '-0.1273530D-01',
 '15h_dEdx': '0.4292434D-03',
 '15h_dEdy': '-0.1418384D-01',
 '15h_dEdz': '-0.7764904D-03',
 '1c_dEdx': '-0.1150239D-01',
 '1c_dEdy': '0.4798462D-02',
 '1c_dEdz': '0.6015413D-05',
 '2c_dEdx': '0.2259669D-01',
 '2c_dEdy': '0.5902019D-01',
 '2c_dEdz': '0.3707704D-02',
 '3c_dEdx': '-0.3153006D-02',
 '3c_dEdy': '-0.4060517D-01',
 '3c_dEdz': '-0.2306249D-02',
 '4n_dEdx': '-0.2718508D-01',
 '4n_dEdy': '0.3404657D-01',
 '4n_dEdz': '0.1334956D-02',
 '5h_dEdx': '-0.1064344D-01',
 '5h_dEdy': '-0.1054522D-01',
 '5h_dEdz': '-0.8032586D-03',
 '6c_dEdx': '0.3017851D-01',
 '6c_dEdy': '-0.2805275D-01',
 '6c_dEdz': '-0.9413310D-03',
 '7s_dEdx': '-0.2253417D-01',
 '7s_dEdy': '0.1196856D-01',
 '7s_dEdz': '0.2069422D-03',
 '8n_dEdx': '-0.3195785D-01',
 '8n_dEdy': '0.1888257D-01',
 '8n_dEdz': '0.3914382D-03',
 '9h_dEdx': '-0.4441489D-02',
 '9h_dEdy': '0.1382483D-01',
 '9h_dEdz': '0.6724659D-03'}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I am wondering if the output could be arranged as well (?) such that '1c_dEdx': '-0.1150239D-01', appears first followed by '1c_dEdy': '0.4798462D-02', and so on?

Comment: It only appears that way because I used `pprint` to print it, which sorts the keys alphabetically.  If you enumerate the dict keys yourself, they'll come out in the order they were inserted: 1c, 2c, 3c, etc.  You can, of course, pull the keys into a list and sort them however you want.

Comment: It will work with any number of atoms.  It would have been quicker for you to try it.